# Make Http.sys work with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, blazor, httpsys

I try to make Window authentication work with Kestrel by following the links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.0#how-to-use-httpsys
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#httpsys

Here is the code.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    options.MaxConnections = null;
                    options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                    options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://localhost:8080");
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseHttpSys(options =>
                    {
                        options.Authentication.Schemes =
                            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM |
                            AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                    });
            });
```

However, browse https://localhost:8080 shows the following error message (Edge)?

> Can’t connect securely to this page
>   This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't have development certification installed on your machine.
try this:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Comment: Should I use the same command if I want to use Kestrel for production? the `dev-certs` sounds like for development only?

Comment: BTW, I got the following error when running the command. `Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.`

Comment: If you want to serve you service as an internal service which isn't exposed directly to public (for example, the upstream of a reverse proxy), you probably should not make you app listen to a https endpoint. Use http instead, otherwise you need a valid https certificate for your app. Simply change the line `options.UrlPrefixes.Add("https://localhost:8080");` to `options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080");`